# Gibbs sampling in R: Error The number of variables in initial values does NOT match no_var

Tags: r

I have a sample of 50 random variables that follows a gamma (5,5) distribution. I have stored the vector of the variables as y i. e. `y<-c(5.888242, 4.828093,...`
Now, the r.variables are of two types; type 1 and type 2. I have stored the types vector as s i. e `s<-c(1, 2, 1, 1,...` 
The probability of obtaining a variable of type 1 is 0.7, implying that if the length of `y` is `50`then I would expect to have `35`variables of type 1.

I am trying to use Gibbs sampling technique to obtain a sample of length `35`, belonging to type 1, as well as another sample of length `15` belonging to type 2. I have the following code for obtaining a sample of type 1:

```
library(gibbs.met)
log_gamma<-dgamma(y,5, 5, log = TRUE)
gibbs_met(log_f = log_gamma,no_var = 35,
          ini_value = 0,iters = 500,
          stepsizes_met = 0.5)
```

When I run the above code, i get an error

```
The number of variables in initial values does NOT match no_var
```

Kindly assist on how to go about it.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I'm not familiar with gibbs_met, actually I don't know what I'm doing here. But there a few things to change in your code to work

```r
gibbs_met(log_f=dgamma,
  no_var = 1,
  ini_value = 1,
  iters = 500,
  iters_met = 2,
  stepsizes_met = 0.5, 
  shape=5, rate=5, log=TRUE)
```

First `gibbs_met` needs the log_function, so you have to provide an actual function not a vector based on a given distribution. The arguments of the function `dgamma` are given to `gibbs_met` as stated above.

Second `ini_value` is a vector of length `no_var`. So either `no_var = 1` (for ini_value being a number) or `ini_value = rep([startvalue],35)` or `ini_value = c( ... )` with length 35 for `no_var = 35`.

The `ini_value` needs to have probability > 0, so `[startvalue]` has to be > 0.

Third the argument `iters_met` is missing, so I set it to `2`.

Please take a closer look at the [Reference manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gibbs.met/gibbs.met.pdf) since I don't know what I'm doing here.